# Is it possible to take simultaneous screenshots of two windows?

Tags: screen-capture

I want to be able to take a screenshot of two windows at the same time without capturing what's in the background. For instance, instead of taking a picture like this:
[image: screenshot of two windows]

I want a picture like this:
[image: screenshot #2]
Obviously it was quickly Photoshopped, but you get the point.
So is this possible?

Comment: Is _at the same time_ an absolute requirement?

Comment: I took a look at possible options using `man screencapture`. No option for simultaneous screen-capture here.

Comment: @MattiSG Yes, that was the intent. I know I can do it by taking individual shots with Cmd+Shift+4+Space, but that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Layers](http://layersapp.com/) - it screenshots the entire screen but saves each object in a separate layer. You then export to PSD or a set of .png (or .tiff) images

Comment: this would be my recommendation also.  the files generated are also compatible with Pixelmator

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! This is pretty much what I was looking for, just a little more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If *at the same time* is an absolute requirement, then [SnapZ Pro X](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/) is the way to go, as for anything screen capture related  :)

In SnapZ Pro, simply select the “Objects” mode, and click on the windows with the <kbd>⇧</kbd> key down.

---

If *at the same time* is not absolute, you can spare some money by simply using the standard Screen Capture application, and using the usual “object selection” capture for each window:

1. <kbd>⌘⇧4</kbd>
2. press <kbd>space</kbd>
3. hover over the window you want to capture
4. click

Comment: $69?!? That really is a lot of money.

Comment: @gentmatt Yeah well, at the same time, that's a very specific requirement. I take it as a professional issue, and only professional solutions can solve this. If it's for only one time, simply use some image editing software, as was done roughly by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 'ALT' and Print screen button separately for each window you want then paste them into the same document?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Could you please explain your answer a bit more? It is not clear to me how you actually save two screen-captures in one document. You can edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume usual software would have trouble to provide a solution which is **both simple and fast at the same time** for these reasons:

- Would you really want the background? It's empty wasted space - no matter whether it's white or transparent.
- What windows do you want to capture? You will always have to manually select them before capturing. That takes time.

I'd go with a command in terminal:

```
screencapture -aCW ~/Desktop/1.png; screencapture -aCW ~/Desktop/2.png
```

The typing may may not be fast, but capturing the pictures is.
This way you can quickly capture two windows of your choice in 'real time'.

You basically skip typing <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> both times.

BTW: This way you can manually choose the image format.